# Tomcat hosting, openshift through GitHub, specific pages hidden?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, openshift

I made a dynamic webproject in Eclipse. Its made in java (which I kind of regret already) and was lookin for a hosting service to put it online. I read through some threads and one service I saw many times was openshift. So I was following the tutorial and it mentions something with getting the code from GitHub. Now the problem is that I want to keep the costs so low as possible so I don't want to pay for a private GitHub account. Is it possible to keep certain pages from the project hidden for public? The things that manages passwords and such?
Maybe its just easier to rewrite it in PHP?

Comment: Are you sure this must come from github only? Other git services arn't allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use another git service than github, for example [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product).

On bitbucket you can create private git projects

Once your bitbucket account and project are created change the openshift's parameter `SOUCE_REPOSITORY_URL` with `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME.git`

Now you can create your project into openshift, it'll clone the hidden repo and no one will be able to see what's in it.

Hope it Helps

Comment: Ill give it a shot, you dont know by any chance an easier host where i can just can upload an WAR file?

Comment: It isn't that simple. See https://blog.openshift.com/deploying-from-private-git-repositories/ and https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-clone-secrets

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Sure this is not a "best practive" at all, but i works fine. I tryed it for some developement/tests, give it a try yourself if you want... It is the simplest answer i can give for his requierements.

Comment: @brechtph I don't know any other free provider like openshift. You should give one more try in it, the CI/CD provided by openshift is amazing :)

Comment: Ty all for the info ^^ ill certainly experimentate with openshift for it but for helpin me out with this project is converted it to PhP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about making certain pages private, make everything public and use [secrets as environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables).  That is, make your passwords a configuration detail, not something that is committed to your repo.